# Regex: Delete all lines between STRING, including STRING, but keep the above line

Tags: notepad++, regex

I'm trying to use Regex to get the object names out of a list. All items have "Type:" directly under its name, so I'm trying to use that.

The list is something like this:

```
Example Object
Type: Example

Description

More Description

Another Object
Type: Test

Description
```

And I want the output to be:

```
Example Object

Another Object
```

I'm new to Regex so I'm not sure where to go from here. If someone could explain how their regex code works, that'd be cool.

Edit now that I understand this site better: I've been trying to learn the syntax and have found a snippet of code that successfully locates the line. `(?-is)^(.*\R){1}(?=.*Type:)` from [here](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/21951/search-for-a-text-and-copy-the-previous-lines-of-codes/3). (I don't know how the syntax before the {1} works, could someone explain?) My attempts to modify this code result in it no longer working, so I'm a bit stuck.

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^((.+\R)Type:)[\s\S]+?(?=(?1)|\z)`
- Replace with: `$2`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
    (               # group 1
        (               # group 2
            .+              # 1 or more any character but newline
            \R              # any kind of linebreak
        )               # end group 2
        Type:           # literally
    )               # end group 1
    [\s\S]+?        # 1 or more any character, not greedy
    (?=             # positive lookahead, make sure  we have after:
        (?1)            # same pattern as defined for group 1
      |               # OR
        \z              # end of file
    )               # end lookahead
```

**Replacement:**

```
$2          # content of group 2
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]